# Java: queue isn't displaying all records

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to add patient records into a queue and then display all the records on the screen but I am not getting them.. I guess the display method isn't working for me.. I probably made a mistake.. Here is my code for queue of the patients.

```
public class Patient_Queue {

    private LinkedList list;

    public Patient_Queue()
    {
        // Create a new LinkedList.
        list= new LinkedList();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (list.size() == 0);
    }

    public void joinQueue(Object item)
    {
        list.add(item);
    }

    public Object Consultation()
    {
        Object item = list;
        list.remove(0);
        return item;
    }

    public void display() {
        for(int q=0;q<list.size();q++)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(q));
        }
    }

    public int size(){
        return list.size();
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        list.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code that adds items to the LinkedList and the code that calls display().

Comment: Also, which type have the objects that go into the queue?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw sure

Comment: What do you need the class `Patient_Queue` for? You could simply use a `java.util.LinkedList` instead (which implements the interface `Queue`)

Comment: q.joinQueue() is what i used for adding in objects and q.display() is what i use to print them out

Comment: @Aloso I am required to use it

Comment: `display()` works, given that `list.size()` and `list.get(int)` work.

Comment: what type object  you add in list? `System.out.println(list.get(q));` You must override toString() for writing `q` object's properties.

Comment: The `Consultation()` method is bizarre (and its name doesn't follow Java naming conventions). Your problem, however, is most likely in your `LinkedList` class, which you haven't shown. Or is this using `java.util.LinkedList`?

Comment: @mustafacil I have created another class called Patient where i added in the name, age, and id and I added the values into it with main class, and then i added those objects into the queue class with q.joinQueue(object reference name);

Comment: @mustafacil so i should create a toString in patient class and thats it?

Comment: @DavidConrad i am using java.util.LinkedList

Comment: If you want to see patient's properties by `System.out.println(list.get(q));`, yes you should override toString().

Comment: What is the test case where you think the `display` method isn’t working? Please provide complete code (for a minimal example), expected output and the way actual output differs. There’s nothing intelligent we can say about “isn’t working”, it’s much too vague.

Comment: And please don’t delete the code containing the error from the question. One of the qualities of Stack Overflow is others can learn from the questions and answers for years to come. When you delete essential information from the question, no one in the future will understand how the answer answers the question.

Comment: If you want to delete the question altogether, I believe you should have a ‘delete’ link right under the question (under the tags).

Comment: As Ken White said [on a later question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220257/java-valid-date-using-if-statement#comment73511574_43220257), please don't tag-spam. This question has nothing to do with arrays, or sorting; I've removed those tags for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a mistake here:

```
public Object Consultation()
{

    Object item = list;

    list.remove(0);

    return item;
}
```

Corrected version:

```
public Object Consultation()
{

    Object item = list.get(0); // fix

    list.remove(0);

    return item;
}
```

Note that LinkedList implements Queue interface and you can use its Queue methods directly.