# java: Valid date using if statement

Tags: java, date

I was wondering how is it possible when scanner is running and asking you to type in the date and you type in an invalid date, that it shows u an error and then makes u type in the valid date again? The thing is, when my program runs, it asks to enter day, month and year, but if the day is wrong, is skips to month without letting the user type in the correct date.. I know how to get the program to detect wrong dates but idk how to get it to cause an error or make you type the right one again rather then skipping to the next question..

```
System.out.println("Enter day for the First date");
Scanner da= new Scanner(System.in);
d=da.nextInt();
date.setDay(d);
```

Comment: can you provide the code which you currently have?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw ok will edit it in

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw there..

Comment: Please stop tag spamming. Your question has nothing to do with Eclipse, arrays or sorting. Your question is about validating a date after user input and looping if it's invalid. There's no sorting, no array, and it has absolutely nothing to do with which IDE you're using or Eclipse in particular. Use the tags that are actually relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to validate and loop for each input variable

somthing like

```
Scanner da= new Scanner(System.in);
d= getDay (da);

private int getDay (Scanner da) {

    int day = 0;
    while (day <= 0 || day > 31) {  // tricky logic required here
       System.out.println ("Enter day between 1 and 31");
       day = da.nextInt ();
    }
    return day;
}
```

rinse and repeat for month and year

**Note**

You will maybe have more logic to apply based upon month/day mis-match e.g. 31 february

Comment: *time* you do not mention time at all in your question

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a full answer, but the gist of it would be something like this-

```
int day;
boolean waiting = true;
while (waiting) {
    day = in.nextInt();
    waiting = isGood(day); //you need to write this yourself!
}
/*continue with program*/
```